# svn checkout of subfolder in non-master git branch

Tags: git, svn, svn-checkout

I would like to checkout a subfolder of a git project (without checking out the whole project) as an svn repository. If it's in the master branch I have no problem, just substituting `tree/master` with `trunk` in the url and `svn checkout [modified url]`.

For example with a url like

```
https://github.com/my-repo/tree/master/some/path
```

To check out only `/some/path` as an svn repo

```
svn checkout https://github.com/my-repo/trunk/some/path
```

How can this be done if instead of checking out something on the master branch I would like to check out something in `tree/my-feature-branch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
svn checkout https://github.com/my-repo/branches/your_branch_name/some/path
```

(`branches/your_branch_name` instead of `trunk`).

Comment: Thank you! For anyone else who might need something similar, you can also check out a tag with `tags` in place of `branches` in Anton's answer.

Comment: It is not valid anymore, the "functionality has gone"